# QGIS Select Features by Expression

Tags: qgis, select

I am trying to figure out what the expression is to find all the roads in a TIGER street layer for a county that are the same as roads in a small selection of roads. The small selection of roads are the result of finding roads close to certain points of interest. Often, the TIGER street layer has multiple segments for a road, for example, say a road is called "HWY 99". There can be multiple records in the attribute table that are called HWY 99. There can also be records called Highway 99 or US 99 or such. For the purposes of this question, I am not worried about the variations on the name, I just want to be able to select all the records that are the same name.

I don't know what the proper expression is to do this. The TIGER layer is called street100k_l_or39 and the layer with the names of the roads I am trying to is called coastalroads. From the street100k_l_or39 attributes table I open the Select by Expression window. I have `FULLNAME in coastalroads`, but that doesn't work. I don't know SQL well and I don't know Python either, but I am guessing that an SQL statement in the Expression would do the trick. Maybe I need to do something like "coastalroads.FULLNAME" on the right side?